# How to convert PKCS#8-formatted PEM private key to the traditional format?

Tags: openssl, private-key, pem, pkcs#8

From OpenSSL 1.0 change log:

> Make PKCS#8 the default write format
>   for private keys, replacing the
>        traditional format. This form is standardised, more secure and doesn't
>        include an implicit MD5 dependency.
>        [Steve Henson]

However, I need the private key file in the previous, traditional format.
Is it possible to convert the pem file from PKCS#8 to the traditional format (using OpenSSL.exe app)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Succeeded to solve that in that way - 
the request:

```
openssl req -configconfigfile.cfg -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout newkey.pem -out newreq.pem 365
```

Then, I converted it to RSA format:

```
openssl rsa -in newkey.pem -out newkey.pem
```

Hope that it will help someone.

Comment: If someone is looking to reverse convert it from traditional to pkcs8 format: `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -in file.key -outform pem -nocrypt -out file.pem`

Answer (score 19):

Using Openssl 3.0 :https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-pkey.html

**Convert from PKCS#1 to PKCS#8:**

```bash
$ cat pkcs1.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

```bash
$ openssl pkey -in pkcs1.pem
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**Convert from PKCS#8 to PKCS#1:**

```bash
$ cat pkcs8.pem
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

```bash
$ openssl pkey -in pkcs8.pem -traditional
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20065522/2162144 for a description of PKCS#1 vs PKCS#8.

Comment: `-traditional` was helpful for PKCS8->RSA.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

**RSA private key**

To convert from PKCS#1 to PKCS#8:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -in private_pkcs1.pem -outform pem -nocrypt \
 -out private_pkcs8.pem
```

To convert from PKCS#8 to PKCS#1  (for OpenSSL <= 1.1 remove the `-traditional` switch):

```
openssl rsa -in private_pkcs8.pem -out private_pkcs1.pem -traditional
```

**RSA public key**

To convert from PKCS#1 to PKCS#8:

```
openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -in public_pkcs1.pem -pubout -out public_pkcs8.pem
```

To convert from PKCS#8 to PKCS#1 (for OpenSSL <= 1.1 remove the `-traditional` switch):

```
openssl rsa -pubin -in public_pkcs8.pem -RSAPublicKey_out -out public_pkcs1.pem -traditional
```

Comment: With openssl v3.0+, it is necessary to add `-traditional` when converting to `PKCS#1`.

Comment: I edited the answer to use the `-traditional` switch (and mention to remove it for OpenSSL <= 1.1) as this answer looked better to me but I got crazy today as it was outdated