# Convert PKCS#1-formatted private key to PKCS#8-formatted private key by java

Tags: java, private-key, pkcs#1, pkcs#8

I have a PKCS#1-formatted private key (generated by opendkim-genkey) like this

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Base64 encoded data

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Now I have to use it in Java to generate java.security.PrivateKey

But Java only support PKCS#8-formatted private key.

I know there is a way to convert from PKCS#8 to PKCS#1 by Java (using Bouncycastle), but is there anyway convert from PKCS#1 to PKCS#8 by Java?

Comment: You can do so using openssl with a command like `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -nocrypt -in pkcs1.key -out pkcs8.key`. Compare [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290435/)

Comment: Thank you, I know that I can do by using openssl command line.
But what I ask is anyway we can do it by java.

Comment: Why? You only have to do this process every few years when you re-key. Why write new Java code when an existing utility already does it correctly?

Comment: Do (did) you need to _convert_ it or only to _use_ it? Those aren't the same. To _use_ a PKCS1 RSAPrivateKey (aka OpenSSL traditional clear) in Java with BouncyCastle see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934846/read-rsa-private-key-of-format-pkcs1-in-java .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I did not come up with this solution myself, it was written by marcoscottwright over at github. [Find the original code here](https://gist.github.com/markscottwright/4bd563fa91e9a72bf1ce12a0ff6567aa)

---

You can do so using BouncyCastle given you have a `PrivateKey k` object.

```
try (ASN1InputStream asn1InputStream = new ASN1InputStream(k.getEncoded()))
{
    DERObject rsaPrivateKey = asn1InputStream.readObject();
    return new PrivateKeyInfo(new AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption), rsaPrivateKey).getDEREncoded();
}
```

Comment: This is only half an answer. OP doesn't have a `PrivateKey` object, he has PKCS#1 formatted RSA private key *in a file*.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk but save my life anyway. This is what I need

Answer (score 4):

Converting a PKCS#1 encoded RSA private key to PKCS#8 that's consumable by vanilla Java is possible using Bouncy Castle's [bcprov](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on) library.

Since the difference between PKCS#1 and PKCS#8 is simply the leading PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier, we can supplement that to get PKCS#8:

```java
byte[] pkcs1Encoded = ...;

AlgorithmIdentifier algId = new AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption, DERNull.INSTANCE);
PrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = new PrivateKeyInfo(algId, ASN1Sequence.getInstance(pkcs1Encoded));

byte[] pkcs8Encoded = privateKeyInfo.getEncoded();
```

This is then consumable by vanilla Java:

```
java.security.spec.KeySpec spec = new java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8Encoded);
java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(spec);
```

However, if you're using Bouncy Castle anyway, you can use their provider and you don't need to explicitly convert PKCS#1 to PKCS#8 since their KeyFactorySpi can consume a `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` with a PKCS#1 shoved into it.

e.g.:

```
java.security.spec.KeySpec spec = new java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs1Encoded);
java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", new BouncyCastleProvider()).generatePrivate(spec);
```

The Bouncy Castle provider can also be registered globally:

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

...

java.security.spec.KeySpec spec = new java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs1Encoded);
java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(spec);
```