# How to provide cert password to mitmdump during the start up

Tags: mitmproxy

I'm trying to automate running of mitmdump binary in ubuntu. I'm providing self generated certs to it using command: `./mitmdump --cert *=mycert.pem`. But help doesn't define any commands to provide the private key pass phrase. How do i provide the password during the start up?

I have tried to provide the input to it using command: `./mitmdump --cert *=mycert.pem <<< "mypassword"`, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line), but it still asks my PEM pass phrase.

If it helps, I'm starting the mitmdump process from java code using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(COMMAND)`. Generating the certs without password isn't really a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [mitmproxy documentation](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/) the `mycert.pem` has to contain both, the certificate as well as the private key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
<private key>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<cert>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<intermediary cert (optional)>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

As you can see Mitmproxy expects a `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` and not an `BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY` hence the provided key is not protected by a password at all.

Optionally you can also add intermediate certificate at the end in case the provided certificate is not a root-CA certificate or a direct child certificate of a known root-CA.

Comment: mycert.pem contains the both private key and the certificate. instead of -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----, I have -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----. mitmdump asks the pass phrase, and if I provide it manually I can capture https traffic just fine. Now, how to provide that pass phrase automatically is big mystery to me.

Comment: You really love the hard way. The simple way would be to convert the RSA PRIVATE KEY structure to a PRIVATE KEY: This question should cover that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8290435/150978