# Differences between "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY" and "BEGIN PRIVATE KEY"

Tags: openssl, rsa, private-key, pem

Hi I was writing a program that imports private keys from a `.pem` file and create a private key object to use it later..
the problem I have faced is that some `pem` files header begin with

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
```

while others begin with

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

through my search I knew that the first ones are `PKCS#8` formatted but I couldn't know what format does the other one belongs to.

Comment: Maybe we can give you a better answer if you post the rest of the file. (kidding)

Answer (score 295, accepted):

See https://polarssl.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem (search the page for "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY") ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140819203300/https://polarssl.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem) for posterity, just in case).

`BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` is PKCS#1 and is just an RSA key. It is essentially just the key object from PKCS#8, but without the version or algorithm identifier in front. `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` is PKCS#8 and indicates that the key type is included in the key data itself. From the link:

> The unencrypted PKCS#8 encoded data starts and ends with the tags:
>
> ```
> -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
> BASE64 ENCODED DATA
> -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
> ```
>
> Within the base64 encoded data the following DER structure is present:
>
> ```
> PrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
>   version         Version,
>   algorithm       AlgorithmIdentifier,
>   PrivateKey      BIT STRING
> }
>
> AlgorithmIdentifier ::= SEQUENCE {
>   algorithm       OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
>   parameters      ANY DEFINED BY algorithm OPTIONAL
> }
> ```
>
> So for an RSA private key, the OID is 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 and there is a RSAPrivateKey as the PrivateKey key data bitstring.

As opposed to `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`, which always specifies an RSA key and therefore doesn't include a key type OID. `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` is `PKCS#1`:

> RSA Private Key file [(PKCS#1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A.1.2)
>
> The RSA private key PEM file is specific for RSA keys.
>
> It starts and ends with the tags:
>
> ```
> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> BASE64 ENCODED DATA
> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> ```
>
> Within the base64 encoded data the following DER structure is present:
>
> ```
> RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
>   version           Version,
>   modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
>   publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
>   privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
>   prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
>   prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
>   exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
>   exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
>   coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
>   otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL
> }
> ```

Comment: For RSA keys, PKCS#1 contains CRT parameters, PKCS#8 doesn't. You can confirm this by looking at sizes. PKCS#8 is smaller even with more headers added. If you care about performance, use PKCS#1. My test shows 3 times faster.

Comment: @ZZCoder, could you please provide some details on how you generated the keys and tested the performance? `openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out key.pem` generates the PKCS#8 key that does include the CRT parameters.

Comment: To generate a *PKCS#1* key the `openssl genrsa` command can be used. Using `openssl req` to generate both the private key and the crt will end up with a *PKCS#8* key. The `genpkey` manual states `The use of the genpkey program is encouraged over the algorithm specific utilities because additional algorithm options and ENGINE provided algorithms can be used.`. But some software (`mysql`) can use only *PKCS#1* keys. Converting from *PKCS#8* to *PKCS#1* can be done with `openssl rsa -in key.pem -out key.pem`. Converting the other way can be done with `openssl pkey -in key.pem -out key.pem`.

Comment: Does this mean PKCS#1 does not define a encrypted RSA private key ?

Comment: OpenSSL 3x has showed up in Ubuntu 22.04. To get a PKCS#1 key you now need to do `openssl genrsa --traditional 2048`

Answer (score 49):

Have a look at [`<openssl/pem.h>`](https://git.openssl.org/?p=openssl.git;a=blob;f=include/openssl/pem.h;hb=HEAD). It gives possible BEGIN markers.

Copying the content from the above link for quick reference:

```
#define PEM_STRING_X509_OLD "X509 CERTIFICATE"
#define PEM_STRING_X509     "CERTIFICATE"
#define PEM_STRING_X509_PAIR    "CERTIFICATE PAIR"
#define PEM_STRING_X509_TRUSTED "TRUSTED CERTIFICATE"
#define PEM_STRING_X509_REQ_OLD "NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST"
#define PEM_STRING_X509_REQ "CERTIFICATE REQUEST"
#define PEM_STRING_X509_CRL "X509 CRL"
#define PEM_STRING_EVP_PKEY "ANY PRIVATE KEY"
#define PEM_STRING_PUBLIC   "PUBLIC KEY"
#define PEM_STRING_RSA      "RSA PRIVATE KEY"
#define PEM_STRING_RSA_PUBLIC   "RSA PUBLIC KEY"
#define PEM_STRING_DSA      "DSA PRIVATE KEY"
#define PEM_STRING_DSA_PUBLIC   "DSA PUBLIC KEY"
#define PEM_STRING_PKCS7    "PKCS7"
#define PEM_STRING_PKCS7_SIGNED "PKCS #7 SIGNED DATA"
#define PEM_STRING_PKCS8    "ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY"
#define PEM_STRING_PKCS8INF "PRIVATE KEY"
#define PEM_STRING_DHPARAMS "DH PARAMETERS"
#define PEM_STRING_DHXPARAMS    "X9.42 DH PARAMETERS"
#define PEM_STRING_SSL_SESSION  "SSL SESSION PARAMETERS"
#define PEM_STRING_DSAPARAMS    "DSA PARAMETERS"
#define PEM_STRING_ECDSA_PUBLIC "ECDSA PUBLIC KEY"
#define PEM_STRING_ECPARAMETERS "EC PARAMETERS"
#define PEM_STRING_ECPRIVATEKEY "EC PRIVATE KEY"
#define PEM_STRING_PARAMETERS   "PARAMETERS"
#define PEM_STRING_CMS      "CMS"
```