# Generate public key from saved private key PHP

Tags: php, openssl

I have saved Private Key in DB in this format e.g.

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
 MIICdgIBADA................CHGIdCtZEmTD7sbLUcFCYDbohnqaWf2d+2I
 EyC/Hg/tS4d+BQ==
 -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I need extract Public Key from it. **openssl_pkey_get_details** need resource, but how can I create resource from string?

I tried this

```
$public_key = openssl_pkey_get_details(openssl_pkey_get_public($private));
```

Error is **openssl_pkey_get_details() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given**

**EDIT 1:**

I'm trying solution from @kbarborak bellow, but $pk_get is false:

```
$pk_string = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n".chunk_split($data[4], 64, "\n")."-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
$pk_get = openssl_pkey_get_private($pk_string);

die(var_dump($pk_string));
```

Output of var_dump is:

```
string(944) "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICjAIBAAINBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAIJKoZIhvcNAQEBAgACggJhMIICXQIBAAKB
gQCvUSrEHS1T5g5z/Yv5ETeXA6CLsdo15Dqk0LevSAXGgbFarSRLfTYtN1/zwqgs
+YWnU/0lZKmzJpmDFRmH/wDeu8o7ptEOrNLgbs6TM85cS4ZmRhJnrOG3G6oBMq5m
UCPw+r06HIuxwyS54/2vY/GGjXpxV59yNUhKh9H9V216YwIDAQABAoGARZAbO/2n
wqaCDZwJMiaWvCEATu2e+8s3SbZXbAFT6VQEn0ocIKfqGz7hn8MZH99SHPbCd1fd
zev+9XglzURtf0sHneq8zT8qT4KYYriRj6dwlyJ6xpf1lLrBqi+eifvZR3+i60Ql
YuBNEXhq/OuSAwV+qTCLYrchUE0jTtX3HWECQQDerLyy1hs2SxlXgLbf80BdIuxB
gqj7QGirYBY/tnPvyLBJWF8RLGjEdPUEaN2hUgkhq2+IQ6lRADKJBQX+1u33AkEA
yY4Hz0rFgjDXx1PLOlX3z6vAFNhtWagcsz+DNp0fwaD1jLVvWnAcAgjJWQ9GBRrC
OGctw6hN92tX19vuKIbr9QJBAIFR1oESIVmlwcD0ysBDOFUezBC7vkG0xVUKB8HW
x3wxlFf0T7ncjbfSqN13vYdL6mu4cZy0lueo8rBqz3GSBz8CQQCTibEzzzL20xQQ
p8jbAfTtgnaPi8G34HRpzbMZ9jg5v74e6u0BEZGe95mT5LdHo0fKi9SXJYs08tGR
hD84UVNFAkAgR+Z0ox6HbNMj5bBIvqEC25mAMnayFyezPZ+/B/IyHDYmQSO9FGsG
/YVA8prMnAZ/YEiCC/2kYA2Ds7GjdJipAgACAAIAAgA=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Extracting public key**

```
// Private key as string
$pem_private_key = file_get_contents('mykey.pem');

$private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private($pem_private_key);

// Public key as PEM string
$pem_public_key = openssl_pkey_get_details($private_key)['key'];
// As PHP resource
$public_key = openssl_pkey_get_public($pem_public_key);

echo $pem_public_key;
echo $public_key;
```

**Preparing private key string**

```
$pk_string = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n".chunk_split($data[4], 64, "\n")."-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
$pk_get = openssl_pkey_get_private($pk_string);

die(var_dump($pk_string));
```

Use BEGIN **RSA** PRIVATE KEY instead just BEGIN PRIVATE KEY (same for END).

Hope that's help.

Comment: I tried this, but $pk_string = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----".$data[4]."-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
 $pk_get = openssl_pkey_get_private($pk_string); ... when call, so $pk_get is false

Comment: What is exactly in $data[4]? You are giving malformed string as private key. I just guess in data[4] is base64 encoded binary representation of private key. If so, try `$pk_string = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" . chunk_split($data[4], 64, "\n") . "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"`.

Comment: Thank you:) I search it minutes before your comment. For one time it was ok it. But second call is false again. Please see EDIT 1 in my post now.

Comment: Ok, I got it. You have to tell that your key is RSA type [http://stackoverflow.com/a/20065522/4632537](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20065522/4632537).

Comment: Right! Thanks. So my next question is - is here way to generate RSA key in PHP directly via openssl or I must use something else?

Comment: It is another question - but shortly yes - openssl_pkey_new(). If my answer helped you, please flag it as solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`openssl_pkey_get_public()` returns false if there's an error. So this is was most likely happens and is passing `false` to `openssl_pkey_get_details()`. Debug you `$private` variable.