# Parse RSA key pair from string in Python

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, pycrypto, key-pair

I'm trying to generate/read a RSA-keypair from the publicKey and the privateKey as a String.

Something like this:

```
priK = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----MIIBOQIBAAJAVJhUS0gLqXLOmVv2xG23oFPwim9+rVxGhLUXqKShQCvB3iRMOHn7/GNJumpwmnglcsNXuqAhN0OxqKGGJdtYdwIDAQABAkBP0VrXnSbDvvuIX+k59Xvo3sp7FDAmSoaO+H9WM9+ht5H/f/geIrSEXSIkFLnzniMwtOJ422GmkDkL1F67HuDhAiEAlNauDiq3RqoXufbauyPEOG9fMS2pvB+auT2XCHJhhKsCIQCRgIo7WIRZYnNpNRWaoppUQK3g+aM8sdeBYpbs2nwDZQIgZXIxrmxFAUAb7d+oVFdbfc/DRSTHhPbRoaKuF87GUwMCIFmzaATsLjO42TPMETSS+BfnBAtFe5hIf3Z5pFgC3h9tAiEAgYjug92fmVvE+CcRSg6at7meSEbK/Kxg7Ar4mlkXMlI=-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

pubK = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MFswDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSgAwRwJAVJhUS0gLqXLOmVv2xG23oFPwim9+rVxGhLUXqKShQCvB3iRMOHn7/GNJumpwmnglcsNXuqAhN0OxqKGGJdtYdwIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

keyPair = RSA.importKey(priK + pubK)
```

My error that I'm getting is:

```
in importKey
    if lines[1].startswith(b('Proc-Type:4,ENCRYPTED')):
```

I don't even know if it's possible like that. I didn't really find information about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RSA.importKey(key)` imports one key. It cannot import concatenated keys.

If you import a private key, then you can extract a public key from that, because common PKCS#1 and PKCS#8 format have all the necessary information to create public key. So, you don't even need to concatenate the public key to it.

Use:

```
privateKey = RSA.importKey(priK)
publicKey = privateKey.publickey()
```

Comment: Hi this does not work actually, with the priK example given by the OP. Any advice on how to make it work?

Comment: @totalMongot Well, it worked at the time. Also keep in mind that the code and suggestion is for pycrypto which is obsolete now. If you have trouble, I would suggest that you ask a new question.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.Do you know what is the replacement for pycrypto?

Comment: pycryptodome I'd imagine.