# python string format pkcs8 RSA signature

Tags: php, python, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

I need to use pkcs8 private key in my project as example below, I can't found any library or  method relate to pkcs8 signature only pkcs1 are available for the `Crypto.Signature`.

My python code example:

```py
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

privatekey='''-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'''

signstr = testdata123

key = RSA.importKey(privatekey) 
h = SHA.new(signstr) 
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key) 
signature = signer.sign(h) 
sign = base64.b64encode(signature)
```

The signature generated by code above do not match the public key in the api system I am using.

For PHP side I am able to sign correctly. The working code for PHP as below:

```php
$private_key= openssl_get_privatekey($private_key);
openssl_sign($signStr,$sign_info,$private_key,OPENSSL_ALGO_MD5);
$sign = base64_encode($sign_info);
```

Any advice on how to sign with RSA pkcs8 format private key using python is much appreciated.

Comment: I hope this isn't your real private key?

Comment: Hi, no it is not it is just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Hash algorithm

Of course, it must be different, because you're using different hash algorithms.

Your Python code uses SHA-1 and your PHP code uses MD5. The default hash algorithm in PHP is `OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1` as the [documentation describes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php):

```
if (!openssl_sign($signStr, $sign_info, $private_key)) {
    echo "Failed to sign";
}
```

#### Key encoding

There are many ways of encoding a private key. Two of the most common ways are PKCS#1 and PKCS#8 encodings. See more information on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20065522/1816580).

The key encoding is not a concern here, because both pycrypto and openssl use the correct one here.

#### Padding

There are two common [padding schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Public_key_cryptography) that are used for signing: PKCS#1 v1.5 padding and RSA-PSS (technically RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5 and RSASSA-PSS). Both of them are defined in PKCS#1, but the latter was introduced in PKCS#1 v2.x.

Pycrypto supports both padding schemes, but openssl only supports PKCS#1 v1.5 in PHP.

#### Compatibility

If you want to check for compatibility of the same algorithm between different languages, you need to sign in one using the private key and verify the signature in the other using the public key. After you've done that, you can try the other way around if you also need the other direction.
This is only relevant for RSA-PSS, because that is randomized.

If you're using PKCS#1 v1.5 padding which is not randomized, you should be able to create a signature in both Python and PHP and compare them directly to check for compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the details explanation