# Difference between `openssl genrsa` and `openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa`?

Tags: ssl, openssl, libressl

It seems that both of the following commands (openssl from LibreSSL) produce private keys. Is there a difference between them? If not, why there are two ways to generate the private keys? Thanks.

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 1024
openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa -out privkey.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:1024
```

Answer (score 9):

Both ways create RSA keys, albeit in different formats. `genrsa` outputs a RSA key in PKCS#1 format while `genpkey` outputs a more generic container which can manage different kinds of keys (like ECC). See [Differences between “BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY” and “BEGIN PRIVATE KEY"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065304/differences-between-begin-rsa-private-key-and-begin-private-key) for more on this.

Note that the [documentation for genpkey](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-genpkey.html) explicitly states that this tool should be used in instead of the algorithm specific genrsa:

> The use of the genpkey program is encouraged over the algorithm specific utilities because additional algorithm options and ENGINE provided algorithms can be used.

Comment: Would you please ellaborate what the algorithm specific utilities are besides `genrsa`? The manpage does not explain this explicitly (I think it should. At least I don't know what it specifically refers to.)

Comment: @user1424739: another algorithm specific tool would be `gendsa`.

Comment: Elliptic Curve (ECC) too. For example:
openssl genpkey -out privkey.p8 -algorithm ed25519