# Generate JSON Web Token (RS256) to access DocuSign using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, jwt, docusignapi, rsa-sha256

I am trying to send envelopes from Docusign using only Apps Script.

```
function createJWT(){
  const header = {
    alg: 'RS256',
    typ: 'JWT',
  };

  const now = Date.now();
  const expires = new Date(now);
  expires.setHours(expires.getHours() + 1);
  const payload = {
    exp: Math.round(expires.getTime() / 1000),
    iat: Math.round(now / 1000),
    iss: "integrator key",
    sub: "user id",
    aud: "url",
    scope: "scopes"
  };

  var toSign = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(JSON.stringify(header)) + '.' + Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(JSON.stringify(payload));
  toSign = toSign.replace(/=+$/, '');

  var privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----<private key here>-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

  const signatureBytes = Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(
    toSign,
    privateKey
  );
  const signature = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(signatureBytes);

  return toSign + '.' + signature;
}
```

**Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature()** returns:

> Exception: Invalid argument: key

How can I create JWT using **RSA Keypairs**? 
Public/Private keys from Docusign: 
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n{public key here}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY----
------BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n{private key here}\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Utilities.base64Encode()` instead of `Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe()`.

Once you make that substitution remove the line with `toSign.replace(...)` and you should be good to go.

---

UPDATE

The above fixes still apply but I think I know what your core issue is. Check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065304/differences-between-begin-rsa-private-key-and-begin-private-key).

`Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature()` expects a private key that starts with `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` not `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`. You'll need to find a 3rd party library compatible with Google Apps Script that can compute keys of the second form (PKCS#1).

Comment: Yes, it solved my issue. I used openSSL to convert the private key wit this line: `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -in private.pem -outform pem -nocrypt -out newPrivate.pem`.