# What is special for a private key to be PEM-formatted?

Tags: python, openssl, public-key-encryption, jwt

I am trying to use the [Google API with a oAuth service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), with Python 3.4. One of the steps is to [generate a JSON Web Token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatingjwt), for which I use [`PyJWT`](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt).

My code for the generation is the following:

```
# opening the certificate downloaded from the Google API console
# it is password protected by the standard password ('notasecret')
p12 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(open('certfromgoogle.p12', 'rb').read(), 'notasecret')

# extracting the private key from the certificate and dumping it to a PEM
# format (FILETYPE_PEM)
private_key = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey())

# at that stage, private_key contains the private key as
# b'-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIICdg(...)FIyw==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'

# trying to get the JWT
encoded = jwt.encode(claim, private_key, algorithm='RS256', headers={"alg": "RS256", "typ": "JWT"})
```

The call to `jwt.encode` crashes with `TypeError: Expecting a PEM-formatted key`. The full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/w_000/PycharmProjects/syncmagazines/testcrypto.py", line 20, in <module>
    encoded = jwt.encode(claim, private_key, algorithm='RS256', headers={"alg": "RS256", "typ": "JWT"})
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\jwt\api.py", line 118, in encode
    key = alg_obj.prepare_key(key)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\jwt\algorithms.py", line 170, in prepare_key
    raise TypeError('Expecting a PEM-formatted key.')
TypeError: Expecting a PEM-formatted key.
```

The private key, however, seems to be extracted correctly.

Why isn't this format correct?

Comment: *"The call to jwt.encode crashes..."* - Is the private key encrypted?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  And could you include the traceback?

Comment: @jww: I updated my code to make it clear that it is available in plaintext

Comment: @frasertweedale: Pythin 3.4, I rewrote my questions with the traceback and other details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having examined the PyJWT source code, it is apparent that the library expects the PEM data to be a string type, but you are providing a bytestring (evident in your question by the `b'...'` literal).
The offending function is [`prepare_key`](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/blob/29f1ef91ab016aa242da1b6ed5a08d51961deb54/jwt/algorithms.py#L158-L170), along with the definition of [acceptable string types](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/blob/5f9bc05803508b844d3fd9c61cd5210af06eecd8/jwt/compat.py#L13-L14).

You must decode the private key data into the native `str` type:

```
private_key_bytes = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey())
private_key = private_key_bytes.decode('utf-8')
```

This only seems to be required for Python 3, but the above code should work for Python 2 as well.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the problem. After adding `.decode('utf-8')` to the `private_key=...` line I got a correct JWT.

Answer (score 0):

> What is special for a private key to be PEM-formatted?

PEM is a presentation encoding. It has the familiar `-----BEGIN XXX-----` and `-----END XXX-----`.

I think *`BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`* is a PKCS #8 private key. Perhaps the library wants a PKCS #1 private key with *`BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`*. *`BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`* is also known as a *Traditional* key encoding (as opposed to PKCS #8).

You should check the relevant documentation and provide the key in the correct format.

To convert from a traditional key to a PKCS #8 key, see the OpenSSL man pages for [`pkcs(1)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs8.html). `-topk8` is of interest. Also see [How to convert PKCS#8-formatted PEM private key to the tranditional format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2957742/608639)

To convert from a PKCS #8 key to a a traditional key, see the OpenSSL man pages for [`rsa(1)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsa.html). Also see [Convert PEM traditional private key to PKCS8 private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8290435/608639)

Comment: The error states that the required format is PEM, which is what I dump (code commented for clarity)

Comment: @WoJ - You provided a PKCS #8 PEM encoded key. Does the library want a PKCS #1 PEM encoded key? PKCS #1 PEM is considered a *Traditional* key in OpenSSL.