# PyJWT, Expecting a PEM-formatted key

Tags: python, rsa, jwt, pem

I have copy pasted this code from Layer:

https://github.com/layerhq/support/blob/master/identity-services-samples/python/controller.py

I have been told two other people ran it successfully on mac machines. I am using a windows 7,  and I am getting the TypeError: Expecting a PEM-formatted key when running the code:

```
#Read RSA key
root = os.path.dirname("__file__")
with open(os.path.join(root, RSA_KEY_PATH), 'r') as rsa_priv_file:
    
    #Not sure about adding the utf-8 AT ALL
    priv_rsakey = RSA.importKey(rsa_priv_file.read())

#Create identity token
#Make sure you have PyJWT and PyCrypto libraries installed and imported
identityToken = jwt.encode(
    payload={
        "iss": PROVIDER_ID,                 # String - The Provider ID found in the Layer Dashboard
        "prn": user_id,                     # String - Provider's internal ID for the authenticating user
        "iat": datetime.datetime.now(),              # Integer - Time of Token Issuance in RFC 3339 seconds
        "exp": datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=30),   # Integer - Arbitrary Token Expiration in RFC 3339 seconds
        "nce": nonce                        # The nonce obtained via the Layer client SDK.
    },
    key=priv_rsakey,
    headers = {
        "typ": "JWS",               # String - Expresses a MIME Type of application/JWS
        "alg": "RS256",             # String - Expresses the type of algorithm used to sign the token, must be RS256
        "cty": "layer-eit;v=1",     # String - Express a Content Type of Layer External Identity Token, version 1
        "kid": KEY_ID               # String - Private Key associated with "layer.pem", found in the Layer Dashboard
    },
    algorithm="RS256"
)

print identityToken
```

I do not know how else my PEM formatted key should be, but it is as follows(I have manually changed the key before posting):

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIICWwIBAAKBgQCWjLl4Hw8PLto2wGGxrpJ0afHQDX2iJ/xqNXyybgG0GxZI344u
> HXxn/bRzH4Z39pw3vGKrvd21hyln5/qaJGoCSb7QHAtdz8pfNF3t96DBcDh2aDMe
> +8W/4mZqiDi2zNqxAnmuv6vSKnU3UyqFpuPCdXFiA8Gt8OqHHLks8MYYjwIDAQAB AoGAII9i9YXSHfiGHV1SQ7l7102qjNK+HzoCr33N8FE2cRuCoFQpTfP2mg8W3ect
> j/h4JN3LgVVZBA+tdtiptHi3rF1W4yNs4pO3xYLJZHoCdG5CjHoMzEf2VwixK6+f
> 8FCCNErG8yxCpcPDH8D0NjMFzJ0t1kwsBQ0w5iSvdY3qtLECQQDgQPVk6W79kNS9
> gBoZAB71yJazQpCwJ2SLYj6aFNZDX1Jpg5GRoVOs59gl13UF+9AwJf5MCIMbqaly
> T1/4aBa1AkEAq9y0DwSjNLl26XeBhWycQJZUu5lsJVqJcx2q0GsKGx5Ntei/48bD
> ldi7ZXWdA6o4OOV2GpW1hX7vssPHBXBYswJAMGXUkDLRAWiAgWVkPIEKLYFdBNMY
> 5uuZh3tsh1R36ZJo9tyuTf/DT026GHCnkOMHy1xnxYEQyqeTKlh3HeVZAQJAIQYC
> r1QTzEDLAaeOAsZQ6/Q3Cek4545TBgSwWuYGhhl3kznLDYiW8oc30xIbfqXJsd0d
> qZQU0jcG9hG6f2gMEwJALHz0jXhpjo+UygUjdKbW/mfKRirSYiGLCYQHiNc4aaDe
> omr9XLu9Hc6aI9RVGIFMnygaI9Ahu2mNkpj5UoaTTA==
>
> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

I couldn't find any solutions to my problem that worked.
Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7; running in shell_plus --notebook, jupyter

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102007/what-is-special-for-a-private-key-to-be-pem-formatted) indicates that `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` is the expected format; you have a different format.  Try converting it (I guess OpenSSL will have the tool).

Comment: Thank you, but in the same question it is said that BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY is also acceptable. I tried the other too, no results. This worked on a mac I was told.

Comment: Just FYI, now that you've publicized that key you can never use it again!

Comment: Thank you! Yes i have manually altered the key before posting it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
priv_rsakey = RSA.importKey(rsa_priv_file.read())
```

to:

```
priv_rsakey = rsa_priv_file.read()
```

Comment: I thinks it's more secure if you remove the file header and footer since the known file headers could help break the key: `priv_rsakey = rsa_priv_file.read().replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "").replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "")`