# Load RSA private key to EVP_PKEY

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, openssl, private-key

I currently have private key in a .pem file. In my App (iOS) I want to load the private Key into a EVP_PKEY struct to sign a X509_REQ.

My current problem is that I'm able to load the private key, but actually it is a different private key than the one in my file system.

Here's my code:

```
BIO *bio_err;
X509_REQ *x509=NULL;
EVP_PKEY *pkey= NULL;
EVP_PKEY *pubKey = NULL;

NSString *privateKeyFile = [SecurityManager privateKeyFileAndProof:YES];
char const *privKeyPath =  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileSystemRepresentationWithPath:privateKeyFile];
FILE *fp = fopen(privKeyPath, "r");

PEM_read_PrivateKey(fp, &pkey, NULL, NULL);

fclose(fp);
CRYPTO_mem_ctrl(CRYPTO_MEM_CHECK_ON);

bio_err=BIO_new_fp(stderr, BIO_NOCLOSE);

PEM_write_PrivateKey(stdout,pkey,NULL,NULL,0,NULL, NULL);
```

This is my actual private key file:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAzl8TJ46uLTo6ELLrEPRpS7S0IYBAhAXbxvvKaRLvjBi9khud
8ybfDSjoD//uoAlZDIfRak31tHIXqiJntaDZJ8ujIEK4DdRBVHowPNC/tKuYUti8
vZ94BkN48nyJwfFtYPtqaMI6XC0Vh0ffQnQ9jl1d8TVfvxuhlK2+C/WG8Gz9NmRu
JGgCiNuHOIIjaDtlJW36fj21KxW5de1dEW1GUF9GPctN0QjeU4xPFukbu0w8qrr7
ShiIlz0DCkzuj2ww1mr/Gpt4boGCmyM9u+IMg30WMGYacb1+qIpswHJIVaDx7Jmf
xnn8k2rVZT5FUpSjyusSeWFkU7Qh0cKm5BrFNQIDAQABAoIBAEJV2Uhb2qz7DHMV
r+2xQq9tFIG4QgSuBWk+wl9oEMwNn9H5QppIImaOgZmzALc8if03Ix9yk8o+6lBr
4r5FR8g88uCJ0bPQSHepFxxVVWnzxnDK7lBdlC0fPx9i3L0Up74G0rt9w1ihvUvQ
1Hj9+FNsu6evKmm5rgSmnHInqApbyivyogqqSFZ1WlbR9PlT7J15RJAL6lVL+6DP
bIyFDL38degVtOUCAekTsBj1tpewfpFYIb6g5ovVFMgbzXBFL8tEmTe40UheUD1R
LBSaBISQQdl1b6dp0A7jPisk6NE9RZRv0aXLf/t1GrCGIVNQ73+ZtJPETL5Ckk3n
+eEWizkCgYEA9Vmg3pfMHB6QAcsEASK+bdOx2p+Sq47Yd4wISWXKpiylYudKFv0I
bm/0fhU3QOwIUpD0/i5dvUetE08ARU8vXHS+Aar9Gr109KslgdoLFnwTp9A9MsJP
Kuo7ZV3/P3APYlsCdoA2YmR8ys6JIooNlwwV523vI0S7q0Jc277tHf8CgYEA11RO
7FpFMYgYniSyal4Sze+YLXbhvhTPdmbhY+zAh3U0aJ4WHckmofeyomgqQ9ZAdcfu
cUyZKqxJ6FQelc5voBjOTj6rNfziWrU618ldIgmW/0hsQ4Wb+j7W+csqJVTPPGCy
bg+jRIv0W9foIPFhXijC/HWS3Vq2QCklGO5kBMsCgYBC1B4AY4KCKkT5aA34LTmH
esEYFp0Bw8/siCT9sQ9IwiJuVSeWKWfxhOcorKi3M1N1Aezpi0GXO/3Fo6AkQNRa
r6XNmICGlxJTTobR3s1kW3mTHSJ+P/UGcHSrQLY01lYqaTW7h2LI3CwtpaIu2UGo
Ye9ZcVVQ2vjvRg07Ab9eiwKBgFrmWlLoYKFiRJIuB6tjfyi0Zld7Ah0OB+6By9A1
F6mXTsKDSe7VBZwGRsDMnFr6zUdrWTs3DMm45ZJQQIEZHoJFNoJNblViJeQI8Yg6
lzhROA8YcauncYsYkAPvQiF0Re/FGk3gCBpdwpAq+vE9NM9dAcM1lwQe0SUQuXpm
2I41AoGBALUMXfvtDKzcHnZ3UjXuVHM/H6gFiOLx9GhQ9K4BMe7nkbKsDnwbw6Z2
124ZdhkBMgFsL8XTyhyGo2upB/Sq9enLT5fNcD3OZcfRfBGgQO/27IV/A5/ofpG6
N3bDZhBhKHvriP683gXF/L2ki4OTtDI6gym/jaXn3RdNK0kL4tJu
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

This is my printed private key, when I've loaded a EVP_PKEY struct

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Usually private keys are stored encrypted with a secret key (password).  You have a NULL password.  Could this be the problem?

Comment: After re-reading, you are trying to read a (potentially) encrypted private key without decrypting and then write it back to a file... using a function that encrypts, then writes the private key using NULL password...  That would make it different.  Try using your password.  (just a guess)

Comment: Actually the key is generated within that App, which runs in a sandbox. So I did not add a key to it

Comment: @Sn0wfreeze - *"this is my actual private key file..."* - be sure to burn that private key after this question.

Comment: Its not really clear what the *problem* is, and what your question is (other than your observations, which you claim is a problem). Possible duplicate of [How to convert PKCS#8-formatted PEM private key to the traditional format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957742/how-to-convert-pkcs8-formatted-pem-private-key-to-the-traditional-format) and [Convert PEM traditional private key to PKCS8 private key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8290435)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OpenSSL version, 1.0.0 , the routines like `PEM_write_PrivateKey` defaults to PKCS8 format which has header and footers like:

> > -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
> >
> > -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

If you want to write in traditional formats in releases later than 1.0.0 call secifically the read and write routines like `PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey` and 
`PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey`

Traditional key format's header and footer are like:

> > -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> >
> > -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I tried to get the key with that method, but it always returns NULL ...

Comment: Is it possible to transfer an RSA struct to an EVP_PKEY struct ? 
I need an EVP_PKEY to sign my X509_REQ

Comment: How about converting traditional encoded PEM key to PKCS#8  format?